# Requests library raises urllib connection error

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

Requests library is giving me an error I've never encountered before, while trying to download an image from my website.

Here is the download function

```
def dl_jpg(url, filePath, fileName):                        
    fullPath = filePath + fileName + '.jpg'                 
    r = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True)              
    open(fullPath,'wb').write(r.content)
```

The URL I'm entering is:
          http://www.deepfrybot.ga/uploads/c4c7936ef4218dbe7014cb543049168b.jpg

Here's the error message

```
Last login: Fri Nov  1 03:36:32 2019 from 116.193.136.13
       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ cd dfb-master
[ec2-user@ip dfb-master]$ sudo python3 mainr.py
enter url (n) if auto: http://www.deepfrybot.ga/uploads/c4c7936ef4218dbe7014cb543049168b.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 183, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdce843ed50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.deepfrybot.ga', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /uploads/c4c7936ef4218dbe7014cb543049168b.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdce843ed50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainr.py", line 32, in wrapper
    return job_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "mainr.py", line 138, in main_p
    dl_jpg(url, get_abs_file('images/'), file_name)
  File "mainr.py", line 67, in dl_jpg
    r = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-
packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.deepfrybot.ga', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /uploads/c4c7936ef4218dbe7014cb543049168b.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdce843ed50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

I'm clueless as to why this is happening, a little help would be much appreciated

Comment: The script is failing to resolve the name 'www.deepfrybot.ga'. Does your EC2 instance have DNS access?

Comment: Yeah .ga domains are basically considered as 'dangerous' thats why amazon blocks em. No worries though, i found a way to get past it!

Comment: @0subscriberswith0videos can you please mention this in an answer? (And then accept it!) Also, is there any public information about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lxop said "

> The script is failing to resolve the name 'www.deepfrybot.ga'. Does
>   your EC2 instance have DNS access?

"
And after checking and researching a bit on it I came to know that some specific EC2 instances/urllib3 are sometimes not able to access free top level domains (like .ga,.ml,.tk) as they have a general tendency to be malicious and also since they generally lack an SSL certificate.
These domains with SSL certificates work fine though!
And if you are hosting on say `heliohost.org` (which i am), simply change the domain in the script from `yourwebsite.ga` to `yourwebsite.yourhost.domain`
That should solve it!